# Calling a function of a component in a state array in react native

Tags: react-native

Kinda new to react/react-native.
I have a list component that contains an array of items in state
The list component sometimes query the server for information, and according to the information he gets from the server, he should update some things in the items state.
For testing purposes, I tried to do the something like the following:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({posts: [<Item key={0} ... >, <Item key={1} ... >]}
}
...
testFunc() {
    ... // get data from server
    this.state.posts[0].updateNewInfoFromServer(new_info);
}
```

But it didn't work, and it printed that the updateNewInfoFromServer function of my item component is undefined (it did the same when I tried to change it to any other function of my item component. It's pretty weird to me that I can't access the component's functions but I am able to access its props).

I also tried to add refs to the Items inside the posts array and then try to call this._myref.updateNewInfoFromServer inside the testFunc(), but I got exactly the same error..
What is the "react" way to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: People normally do not save components in state. It is too wierd. Instead you have to keep data in state and according to that data render components

Comment: Hm, I get it. Indeed it seems it should work better than try to call a function of the component.
Got it, thanks! :)